# Is my proof that "Two lines perpendicular to the same line are parallel" correct?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

My older sibling and his/her teacher said that my proof to the following theorem is wrong:

> Let lines $r$ and $s$ be perpendicular  to line $t$. Prove that $r$ and $s$ are parallel.

My proof:

If lines $r$ and $s$ intersect, then they will form a triangle. The sum of the angles in a triangle is $180^\circ$. But since $r$ and $s$ are perpendicular to the same line, all the angles around them are $90^\circ$, and since the sum of any two angles that are formed by $r, s$ and $t$ is $180^\circ$, a triangle couldn't be formed. This makes $r$ and $s$ parallel.

Is there anything wrong about this proof? What is the fallacy?

Comment: In my opinion, which could be mistaken, you nailed it.  I regard your proof, against the backdrop of *Plane Geometry*, to be perfectly valid.  +1 to your posting.

Comment: I agree. It looks good to me.

Comment: (+1) Same to me

Comment: The first line “If $r$ and $s$ intersect, they will form a triangle” throws me off. Only after reading the rest of the proof did I understand you meant to include $t$ in the formation of the triangle. So I would make that explicit in the first sentence.

Comment: It isn't necessarily wrong, although you need the parallel postulate to prove that the sum of the angles of a triangle is $180^°$. However, this lemma can be done without it, using this weaker lemma: in a triangle $ABC$ the external angle to $A$ is strictly larger than both $\widehat B$ and $\widehat C$. As a consequence, no triangle can have two right angles, because otherwise there would be an external angle equal one of the other two angles.

Comment: Judging proofs about fundamental properties can tricky, since it's not always clear to us what results you already know. (Different texts, and different instructors, can introduce things in different orders.) Here, for instance, it's important to know whether you've already "officially" proven that the sum of the angles in a triangle is $180^\circ$.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what part of your proof they believed was incorrect.

Comment: @Gregory I don't even know what's incorrect. But according to everyone who commented, the proof is fine.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Maybe that's why my sibling's teacher got confused.

Comment: This theorem is usually proven BEFORE the parallel postulate is introduced, that is BEFORE the theorem on the sum of the angles of a triangle is deduced. That's probably the reason the teacher marked your proof as wrong: you are not allowed to use that theorem.

Comment: The usual proof makes use of [Euclid's exterior angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your proof isn't exactly wrong, I can see why the teacher thought its a fallacy. The fact that the sum of all internal angles of a triangle is $180°$ is in fact proven via the parallel lines postulate, something you have NOT yet proven (according) to this problem. So you can't use a preexisting result to prove the original theorem as that would be circular reasoning and fallacious. The easiest way to prove it, in my opinion, is constructing a diagram according to the given instructions and use the fact that, since two alternate angles are equal, the lines are parallel to each other.